# Can't find variable using GetValueChar

Tags: python, spss

I'm trying to create a small python program inside SPSS to edit the values of a table.
  I put a piece of the code bellow.
  The problem is happening on the GetValueChar method. It keeps giving me "The variable is not in the active dataset" and I couldn't find why.
  To test, put the two lines commented and tried, it worked. Now I'm sure there is a variable with name 'Estado' on the dataset. I commented the two lines again and the error happened.
  Does anyone know what is wrong?

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import spss, spssaux

for i in range(spss.GetVariableCount()):
   print(spss.GetVariableName(i))

cur=spss.Cursor(accessType='w')
#cur.SetVarNameAndType(['Estado'],[60])
#cur.CommitDictionary()
for i in range(cur.GetCaseCount()):
   row = cur.fetchone()
   cur.SetValueChar("Estado","Estado")
   cur.CommitCase()
cur.close()
END PROGRAM.
```

Comment: I "found" the problem. The SetValueChar method only works when you create a variable under the same cursor instance. It seems a design decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a call to GetValueChar, and there is no such api, but one possibility is that variable names in the Python apis are case sensitive.  Are you sure that you have matched the case?
You might want to try running the spss.Cursor class examples in the Python programmability help as an exercise.

Comment: Sorry. The problem is with SetValueChar.